# 2 sibling nested transactionScope gives: the Transaction has aborted

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, transactionscope

this code gives me the error: **the Transaction has aborted.**
if I remove 1 nested transaction than it doesn't throw

```
  using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        repo.Insert(new Foo {Fname = "aaaa"});
        using(var s = new TransactionScope())
        {
            repo.Insert(new Foo { Fname = "aaaa" });

            //if I remove this transaction it is not going to throw exception
            using (var aaa = new TransactionScope())
            {
                repo.Insert(new Foo { Fname = "aaaa" });
            }

            using(var ssa = new TransactionScope())
            {
                repo.Insert(new Foo { Fname = "aaaa" });
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What statement does throw the error? I'd assume it is the last `repo.Insert`.

Since you don't call scope.Complete(), the transaction is rollbacked (aborted) when aaa is disposed.
Generally, transaction rollback is considered an error, so all higher-level transactions also become uncommittable (or are immediately rollbacked).
So, for the last `repo.Insert` there is no valid transaction to use - that's why it throws an exception.

Answer (score 4):

You might need to specify the TransactionScopeOption like in this example from MSDN:

```
using(TransactionScope scope1 = new TransactionScope()) 
//Default is Required 
{ 
     using(TransactionScope scope2 = new 
      TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required)) 
     {
     ...
     } 

     using(TransactionScope scope3 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)) 
     {
     ...
     } 

     using(TransactionScope scope4 = new 
        TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)) 
    {
     ...
    } 
}
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx

Answer (score 2):

yes, it will work. You`ve forgotten to include scope.Complete(); at the end

Comment: @user281180 I did that on purpose, I don't want it to commit, and it throws me an error